# "sample" and "rbinom" functions in R

Tags: r, sample, simulate

I guess it has been asked before, but I'm still a bit rusty about "sample" and "rbinom" functions in R, and would like to ask the following two simple questions:

a) Let's say we have:

```
        rbinom(n = 5, size = 1, prob = c(0.9,0.2,0.3))
```

So "n" = 5 but "prob" is only indicated for three of them. What values R assigns for these two n's?

b) Let's say we have:

```
        sample(x = 1:3, size = 1, prob = c(.5,0.2,0.9))
```

According to R-help (?sample):

```
     The optional prob argument can be used to give a vector of weights    
     for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.  
     They need not sum to one, but they should be non-negative and not all zero.
```

The question would be: why "prob" does not need sum to one?

Any answers would be very appreciated: thank you!

Comment: Why should they necessarily sum to 1? A weight of `c(3,1)` is just as valid as `c(0.75,0.25)`. And I gather R will just recycle weights to length `n` as per `rbinom(n = 5, size = 1, prob = c(1,0))` where the weights will be `1,0,1,0,1`

Comment: Internally R will recycle if necessary and do `prob=prob/sum(prob)` before using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for `rbinom`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Binomial.html):

> The numerical arguments other than n are recycled to the length of the result.

This means that in your example the `prob` vector you pass in will be recycled until it reaches the required length (presumably 5).  So the vector which will be used is:

```
c(0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2)
```

As for the `sample` function, as @thelatemail pointed out the probabilities do not have to sum to 1.  It appears that the `prob` vector gets normalized to 1 internally.